# Außer Sprachen hatte er ein weiteres Hobby, und zwar -/den Sport

Tags: difference, article

> Außer Sprachen hatte er ein weiteres Hobby, und zwar - Sport.
>
> Außer Sprachen hatte er ein weiteres Hobby, und zwar **den** Sport.

Ich will mit diesem Satz sagen, dass er allgemein -/den (?) Sport mochte.

Answer (score 2):

Beide sind richtig. Der erste gilt für den allgemeinen Fall den du nach den Optionen geschrieben hast. Jedenfalls würde ich den Satz ohne *-* schreiben.

Der zweite Satz wäre richtig, wenn ein gewisser Sport schon erwähnt worden wäre. Dann ist *der* ein Demonstartivpronomen.

Answer (score 2):

Beides ist richtig. Wenn es um die eigene sportliche Aktivität geht, würde ich den ersten Satz bevorzugen.

Falls die Person leidenschaftlich Fußball, die Olympischen Spiele etc. schaut und sich für die Leistungen bestimmter Teams und Sportler interessiert, würde ich dagegen zur zweiten Variante greifen (quasi "der Sport" als Synonym für "die Welt des Sports").

Answer (score 1):

Beide sind richtig, auch wenn du den Sport im Allgemeinen meinst, vergleichbar mit:

> *Sein Hobby ist die Literatur.*
>
> *Ihr Hobby ist das Segelfliegen.*

Persönlich finde ich die Version mit Artikel schöner, aber das ist Geschmackssache.

Ein Beispiel für die Verwendung von Sport in der allgemeinen Bedeutung *mit* Artikel ist das Lied [*Es lebe **der** Sport*](https://youtu.be/beua3WIN19Q) von Rainhard Fendrich.

Wenn du davor schon einen bestimmten Sport erwähnt hättest, *müsste* sogar der Artikel stehen, zum Beispiel im Satz:

> Sie spielt seit zehn Jahren Tennis im Verein. Ihr Hobby ist neben **dem** Sport auch die Literatur.

Hier bezieht sich *Sport* auf *Tennis*.

Comment: Könnte man sagen: Sein Hobby ist Literatur. (ohne Artikel)

Comment: @Taman Ja, aber meiner Einschätzung nach kommt das seltener vor als die Variante mit Artikel.